# how can i set to page 1 in pagination when i search in gridview in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have total `350` records in grid, When i search with "test" it shows me `80` records it is working fine for me but my problem is if i will be on 6th page then if i search with "test" it shows me 80 records but pagination takes default page to 6, but i wants to that page to 1. how can i resolve this issue ? I tried a lot with googling but didn't get any proper solution for this, Can anyone please give me some solution so can resolve this issue, is there anything easiest solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Update as below:

on click on Search button Set Grid page index to zero before binding grid as below:

GridName.CurrentPageIndex = 0;

Comment: Are you sure this is for Yii2?